# Setting up an email server on an ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, mail-server

The machine has a dedicated ip and a domain name.

I need the ability to send and receive emails. I would be needing maximum 5 emails(info,contact,sales etc)

There would be maximum 5 email ids which would be created. Ultimately I want to add these email accounts to my gmail account, ie I want to send and receive emails from my gmail account. So if I am forwarding my emails to gmail, do I need an email server on my domain at all? What is the simplest thing to do.

I have tried installing dovecot but it seems very complex with lot of configuration. Is there any simple email server?

Is there any simple server which just forwards all the emails to my gmail.

Roundcube web mail client is also installed. It asks for Imap username password.

I am not sure what all software I need to install to get this done in the most simple manner.

My requirements are very simple, I do not want a scalable solution, simplicity is the key.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple way: use postfix!

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

During this installation, choose "Internet site with smarthost". You will need information about your ISP's smtp server, through which you will relay outgoing mail.

Set up you email addresses forwarding in /etc/aliases, like so:

```
john.smith:  <your first gmail address>
foobar:      <your second gmail address>
... and so on
```

When you're done, run:

```
sudo newaliases
```

Any incoming mail to john.smith@yoursite.com, foobar@yoursite.com etc will be forwarding to the gmail accounts.

Comment: can emails be received without installing an imap server?

Comment: Yes, by all means. Especially if you forward them to another mail server right away. But even if you keep them on the server, no imap server is strictly neccessary: incoming email will instead be stored in /var/mail/username, where use can access them through command-line email clients.

Comment: Also, should you choose to install an imap server later, it will cooperate nicely with postfix. The standard setup for a mail server on Ubuntu is: postfix for recieving and sending emails, dovecot (or courier) for imap support.